# python/pandas - converting column headers into index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The data I have to deal with treats hourly data as the columns. I want to convert this as an index. Sample looks like this:

```
 year    month    day    1    2    3    4    5    ...   24
 2015      1       1     a    b   ...................    c
 2015      1       2     d    e   ...................    f
 2015      1       3     g    h   ...................    i
```

I want to make the output file something like this:

```
 year    month    day   hour value
 2015      1       1     1     a  
 2015      1       1     2     b 
  .        .       .     .     . 
 2015      1       1     24    c 
 2015      1       2     1     d
  .        .       .     .     .
```

Currently using python 3.4 with the pandas module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df.set_index(['year','month','day'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='value')
         .rename(columns={'level_3':'hour'}))

   year  month  day hour value
0  2015      1    1    1     a
1  2015      1    1    2     b
2  2015      1    1   24     c
3  2015      1    2    1     d
4  2015      1    2    2     e
5  2015      1    2   24     f
6  2015      1    3    1     g
7  2015      1    3    2     h
8  2015      1    3   24     i
```

Another solution with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['year','month','day'], var_name='hour')
         .sort_values(['year', 'month', 'day','hour']))

   year  month  day hour value
0  2015      1    1    1     a
3  2015      1    1    2     b
6  2015      1    1   24     c
1  2015      1    2    1     d
4  2015      1    2    2     e
7  2015      1    2   24     f
2  2015      1    3    1     g
5  2015      1    3    2     h
8  2015      1    3   24     i
```