# Order two tables from one excel sheet with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

I received the following tables besides each other in one excel file and need to order them  into one table with the column names **Name**, **Blue**, **Green**, **Year**.
The names are the same for both tables and the indicator is the same in the whole column
. There is one empty column between these tables.

This is the sheet I received:

| Name | Indicator | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |  | Name | Indicator | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | blue | 524 | 108 | 387 |  | Name 1 | green | 92 | 872 | 90 |
| Name 2 | blue | 77 | 274 | 50 |  | Name 2 | green | 402 | 312 | 528 |
| Name 3 | blue | 201 | 774 | 18 |  | Name 3 | green | 457 | 827 | 20 |
| Name 4 | blue | 35 | 100 | 129 |  | Name 4 | green | 183 | 428 | 510 |

This is how it should look like:

| Name | Blue | Green | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 524 | 92 | 2016 |
| Name 1 | 108 | 872 | 2017 |
| Name 1 | 387 | 90 | 2018 |
| Name 2 | 77 | 402 | 2016 |
| Name 2 | 274 | 312 | 2017 |
| Name 2 | 50 | 528 | 2018 |
| Name 3 | 201 | 457 | 2016 |
| Name 3 | 774 | 827 | 2017 |
| Name 3 | 18 | 20 | 2018 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Is there any way to do this with pandas?**

Comment: let me know if the below answer is useful if not we can insert the data after the empty column in a different by writing in simple script, the same workbook and read two sheets into two dataframes. after that we can do the merge.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But I found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430940/python-pandas-converting-column-headers-into-index

Answer (score 2):

you can use merge on in pandas to do this.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

seperate the data into two dataframes.

call one df_one and another df_two then merge.

```
merged_df = df_one.merge(df_two, how = "right")
```